# Custom Control Storyboard Template Binding Not Working - XAML C#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10-universal

I created a custom Control which has some Dependency Properties which values I also Need to assign to the storyboard in the ControlTemplate.

Here is the beginning of the Code of my `Control Template`:

```
 <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:RingPresenter">
                <Grid x:Name="RootGrid">
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="StatisticUpdateAnnimation">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames EnableDependentAnimation="True" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RingSlice.EndAngle)" Storyboard.TargetName="ringSlice">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="45"/>
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.2" Value="{TemplateBinding Angle}">
```

The Important part is the `Value={TemplateBinding Angle}"` - the value is getting applied succesfully to my

```
 <helper:RingSlice InnerRadius="100" Radius="150"  StartAngle="0" EndAngle="{TemplateBinding Angle}"  Fill="DarkCyan" x:Name="ringSlice">
                        </helper:RingSlice>
```

... **which is part of my Control Template**, but in the storyboard the value is staying 0. The Debugger is saying that `Angle`has the correct value and it is working fine for my Ringslice and even the metadata should be 45.

Why is this value not applied to my storyboard? How can I fix this?

Comment: can you post more of the ControlTemplate content ? I don't understand where <helper:RingSlice> is in relation to the main ControlTemplate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When in doubt, swap `EndAngle="{TemplateBinding Angle}"` for `EndAngle="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Angle}"`.

TemplateBinding is quick and useful but doesn't always have the strongest capacity to feed through information it's bound to, for reasons that escape me entirely.

Comment: Ty now it is working, I'll take a look at the different binding Options available and what the capability of them is